# Why does Firefox keep saying its accessing addonfiles.com?

Tags: firefox, internet, website

Bottom left of Firefox window, a little message keeps appearing, telling me what Firefox is doing.

It keeps saying "connecting to addonfiles.com...". And the message just stays there, seemingly without end.

All the while, the open tab shows a 'busy' indicator, tick-tocking.

What's it doing?

Comment: It is by default. Firefox shows the connection status when it opens websites.

Comment: If on all websites then it could be a browser extension, possibly tracking you. The Network tab of the developer tools should tell you what the request is about. If the message is hanging, the server is not replying: maybe down or overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox Add-on 'Copy All Links' appears to be responsible for constantly attempting to load content from 'addonfiles.com' on every page visited. Removing that Add-on has eliminated the issue.

<-- tl;dr -->

For about the last week, I'd noticed that 'addonfiles.com' kept showing up in NoScript, attempting to load on *every* page in Firefox. I marked it as 'Untrusted', but I was extremely concerned that I was consistently seeing that domain appear.

I discovered via [WHOIS](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/whois/results.aspx?domain=addonfiles.com) that the domain was only recently registered on 2018-04-15 -- brand new domain with no reputation (#RedFlag). Further digging turned up nothing definitive, but I did find a [microblog reference](https://cybre.space/@sireebob/99887757359448775) to 'addonfiles.com' tying it to the 'Copy All Links' Add-on.

It now appears that particular Add-on has been taken down. The official [Firefox Add-on page for 'Copy All Links'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-all-links/) states that "This add-on has been removed by its author."

HTH...

-=B

Answer (score 1):

## Additional Plugin/Links

It seems it might be more than just '*Copy All Links*'. I could break it down to the '*Instant Download Manager (IDM)*' Plugin.

It wouldn't just connect to **addonfiles.com** but also to: **cdnlvry.xyz**, **devappgrant.space**, **eluxer.net**, **urlvalidation.com**, **worldnaturenet.xyz**.

## A bit more analyzing

Those other sites are not as new as **addonfiles.com** and are known to be **malicious**. Taking a look at the the contact emails they are using some 3rd party service to register the site (**whoisguard.com** (new) and **whoisprivacycorp.com** (old)). It seems clear, that this is some malware/phishing attempt. Since it happened recently with an update, it might just be, that the origin got hacked. Nevertheless an security issue.

---

### Recommendation

Use a tool like uMatrix (from the maker of uBlock Origin) for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en), and block external scripts, Cookies & Co (defaults are ok if you trust the origin site). Might be a bit pain to set up, but You'll notice s.t. like that easily (and it get's blocked by default). Then disable the plugins one by one and restart (even if instantly disabled, it might have set some options only cleaned at restart)